# Broken Links even though features haven't moved

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-source

I've been running into an issue on all of my workspaces as of late where the links to random features are broken. I check the source through the layer properties and connect to the EXACT same path when repairing the links. I have no issues with reconnecting or "repairing" the broken links, however it gets annoying when every morning when I load up the same work space I have to repair the broken links before starting my day (I save after I repair these broken links almost every morning). I always have relative paths set on all my MXDs and have checked to make sure it didn't somehow get turned off. Not sure if this is just a bug in the company server or if it's user error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Reset your application profile](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-desktop-installation-support-docs/resetting-your-arcgis-desktop-arcmap-application/ta-p/913597) by shutting down ArcGIS.  Rename your normal.mxd to old.mxd.  Restart ArcGIS.

Unfortunately this will require you to reset data paths, menus, and re-add custom toolboxes.